# Vue: Accessing elements of a bound variable containing an array

Tags: vue.js

I have a variable in my Vue object containing an array, and when I try to access it in mustache notation it's an empty array.

I've tried showing it with array notation, and I've successfully surfaced a scalar variable from the same vue object and scope.

I have a Vue instance (trimmed down a bit):

```
MyVueInstance = new Vue({
    el: '#application-component',
    data() {
        return {
            form_in_progress: [],
            myvar: "foo"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setFormInProgress: function(key, value){
            this.form_in_progress[key] = value;
        },
        addAllFieldsToFormInProgress: function (step, currentform) {

            console.log('addAllFieldsToFormInProgress: step:' + step);

            console.log(MyVueInstance.$refs);
            console.log(MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform].length);
            for (i = 0; i < MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform].length; i++) {
                MyVueInstance.setFormInProgress(MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform][i].name,
                MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform][i].value);
                console.log('Name: ' + MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform][i].name + " value: " + MyVueInstance.$refs[currentform][i].value);

            }
            console.log("form_in_progress:");
            console.log(MyVueInstance.form_in_progress)
            console.log("end of addAllFields...");
        }
    }
 }
```

IN a caught event, I'm able to do:

```
mounted: function () {
    Event.$on('step2', function () {
        console.log('caught event step2');
        // applicantform is a ref= on the form.
        MyVueInstance.addAllFieldsToFormInProgress(2, 'applicantform')
    });
}
```

I can see my console logs producing a good dump of MyVueInstance.form_in_progress.  (The events do not have "this" in scope,
so I have to specify the Vue instance. )

The dump looks like so:

```
[_token: "dyUPurwtLLrXsxEBOsCfZULfETjW3auSI9utn1GH", hoh-first-name: "", hoh-middle-initial: "", hoh-last-name: "", hoh-ssn: "111-11-1111", …]
button: ""
hoh-citizenship: ""
hoh-dob: "month day, year"
hoh-email: ""
hoh-ethnicity: ""
hoh-first-name: ""
hoh-home-number: ""
hoh-last-name: ""
hoh-middle-initial: ""
hoh-mobile-number: ""
hoh-needs-accommodation: ""
hoh-needs-accommodation-type[]: "Sight"
hoh-notifications: "1"
hoh-race[]: "5"
hoh-sex: ""
hoh-ssn: "111-11-1111"
hoh-work-number: ""
physical-apt-suite-other: ""
physical-city: ""
physical-mailing-check: "1"
physical-state: ""
physical-state_input: ""
physical-street-address: ""
physical-zip: ""
_token: "dyUPurwtLLrXsxEBOsCfZULfETjW3auSI9utn1GH"
length: 0
```

When I get past step 2, I try to echo out the variables using mustache notation or a v-for.

```html
    {{ myvar }} - {{ form_in_progress}}
    <ul>
        <li v-for="value,key in form_in_progress">{{key}}</li>
    </ul>
```

I discover that (on the first line above, I can successfully surface myvar, but form_in_progress displays an empty array,
and the v-for loop does not run, behaving as if form_in_progress is empty, which is consistant with echoing out a
pair of empty square brackets.

So I wonder why my scalar variable (myvar) is in scope, but my array (form_in_progress) is in scope but empty.
If it were out of scope I'd expect an error, not a pair of empty square brackets.
Just for fun I tried echoing out form_in_progress.length, and indeed, it's zero.

One thing I notice is that myvar was initialized as "foo" in code, while form_in_progress was dynamically filled in a method.

Can somebody explain how to get the values in form_in_progress to be in scope?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Directly assigning to a particular index in an array is not reactive: [List rendering caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), try `this.form_in_progress.splice(key, 1, value);`.

Answer (score 0):

Directly assigning to a particular index in an array is not reactive: [List rendering caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue **cannot** detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

Instead, try `this.form_in_progress.splice(key, 1, value);`.

---

Consider the following example:

`changeWithBrackets` will do what your code does effectively:

```
this.form_in_progress[key] = value;
```

`changeWithSplice` will do what I propose:

```
this.form_in_progress.splice(key, 1, value);
```

Demo:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["foo", "bar", "fizz", "buzz"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeWithBrackets() {
      this.items[0] = "world";
    },
    changeWithSplice() {
      this.items.splice(0, 1, "world");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="changeWithBrackets">Change with brackets</button>
  <button @click="changeWithSplice">Change with splice</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that I didn't specify that my keys are alphanumeric.  Further reading indicates that form_in_progress is an object, not an array.  So .splice doesn't work.  I I tried using Object.assign, but that doesn't seem to trigger reactivity either.